# Problem using 2 columns as foreign key in sqlite

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a database in sqlite3 and as a part of my schema I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "analysis" (
    "id" INTEGER,
    "project_id" INTEGER,
    "project_year" INTEGER,
    "analyst_id" TEXT CHECK(length("analyst_id") BETWEEN 2 AND 3),
    "analyte" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "pharma_form" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "lot" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "months" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "analysis" TEXT NOT NULL CHECK("analysis" IN ('development', 'validation', 'stability')),
    "start" DATE,
    "end" DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT FK_id_year FOREIGN KEY ("project_id", "project_year") REFERENCES "projects"("id", "year"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("analyst_id") REFERENCES "analysts"("id")
);
```

When I try to insert data into this table I get this error: INSERT failed: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed.

This is the other table, the one the foreign key references to:

```
CREATE TABLE "projects" (
    "id" INTEGER CHECK("id" BETWEEN 0 AND 99),
    "year" INTEGER CHECK("year" BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999),
    "api" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "analyst_id" TEXT CHECK(length("analyst_id") BETWEEN 2 AND 3),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id","year"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("analyst_id") REFERENCES "analysts"("id")
);
```

And this is one row of the csv file I'm trying to insert into the first table:

```
id,project_id,project_year,analyst_id,analyte,pharma_form,lot,months,analysis,start,end
2303028,02,2000,AF,Verapamil Clorhidrato,tablet,1,36,stability,13/03/2023,
```

Can anyone tell me how should I code the table to be able to use 2 columns altogether as a foreign key?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this means that you're trying to insert some data that violates one of the foreign key constraints

Comment: I think so too, but I don't understand why nor how to fix this.

Comment: Here's a sample of the data I'm trying to insert: 
```id,project_id,project_year,analyst_id,analyte,pharma_form,lot,months,analysis,start,end
2303028,02,2000,AF,Verapamil Clorhidrato,tablet,1,36,stability,13/03/2023,
```